# Resque scheduler log not writing to log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque-scheduler

I have an application with resque and resque-scheduler configured.  The jobs all run fine and resque logs output to its log file.  The resque-scheduler alos works fine, loading and processing the jobs as expected.

The one problem I have is the scheduler does not seem to log anything to its log file.

I followed the setup instructions here

https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler#logging

And have this code in my initializer.

```
# Define the location of the schedule
Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'scheduled_jobs.yml'))

# Define the logger
Resque::Scheduler.configure do |c|
  c.quiet = false
  c.verbose = false
  c.logfile = File.open("#{Rails.root}/log/resque_scheduler.log", 'w+')
  c.logformat = 'text'
end
```

When the application is started the resque_scheduler.log is created.

When I start the scheduler it outputs the following to the stdout (terminal window on my VM).  I would have expected this to have gone into the log file.

```
$ rake resque:scheduler TERM_CHILD=1
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2015-07-17T14:34:27+01:00: Starting
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2015-07-17T14:34:27+01:00: Loading Schedule
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2015-07-17T14:34:27+01:00: Scheduling daily_job_email_overdue_items_to_admin 
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2015-07-17T14:34:27+01:00: Scheduling daily_job_to_update_status_to_overdue 
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2015-07-17T14:34:27+01:00: Schedules Loaded
```

I've done a search of the internet but haven't found anyone with the same problem.  Anyone experienced the same problem or has it working and can suggest what I am missing.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just passing a path (string) for `c.logfile`? E.g. `c.logfile = Rails.root.join("log/resque_scheduler.log").to_s`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use the LOGFILE environment variable when creating the rake task. If the file doesn't exist then it will create it anyway.  The basic rake task to start the scheduler that specifies the log file is as follows.

```
rake resque:scheduler LOGFILE=./log/resque_scheduler.log
```

Feel a bit stupid that that I didn't think of this before.  I had just assumed the scheduler would work in the same way as resque and grab the logfile details from the initializer.